# Process exited with return value 3221225477

Tags: c

i am writing this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
FILE *fp;
int i;
fp = fopen("keimeno.txt","r");
fscanf(fp,"%d",i);
printf("%d\n",i);
    fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

and the file contains:

```
2
Yiannis Ioannou 356
3
Today
10347
If
345
And then none
1542
John Smith 743
2
My story
3940
Feedback
682
END
```

When I try to run it, it exits me value `3221225477` instead of printing the number 2..

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: FYI: The return value in hex is 0xC0000005 or STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you scan a number, you need to pass the address of the variable where you want to store the result:

```
fscanf(fp,"%d",&i);
```

where you have

```
fscanf(fp,"%d",i);
               ^  missing the & sign!
```

Your compiler really ought to have warned you - do you enable warnings when you compile?

What is happening here is that the `fscanf` function writes to the location given (in your case, it writes to whatever location is *pointed to* by the *value* of `i`, instead of writing to the *location of `i`*) . This can corrupt your memory in all kinds of nasty ways - resulting, in your case, in the program "running" for considerable time before crashing.

As @Brandin pointed out, there is a further problem with your code (although it's less likely to be the source of your problem). When you attempt to open a file, you should ALWAYS check that you succeeded.  You do this with something like this:

```
#include <assert.h>
// at the top of the program


// attempt to open the file:
fp = fopen("keimeno.txt","r");
// and check whether you succeeded:
assert(fp != NULL); // this says "check fp is not NULL. Otherwise, quit."
```

Alternatively, you can make things a bit prettier with:

```
const char *fileName = "keimeno.txt";
const char *mode = "r";
if((fp=fopen(fileName, mode))==NULL) {
  printf("cannot open file %s\n", fileName);
  return -1;
}
```

It is almost always a good idea to put "hard wired values" near the start of your program, rather than embedding them in a function call.

Comment: In addition to this, the OP should check the return value after fopen. Assuming that it always works will also easily lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @Brandin you are right - but usually a `fscanf` with a NULL pointer will give a more predictable error message. I will update my answer to include this information.

Comment: thank you it worked...thats not my code exacly...in my code i am checking if the file could be opened

Comment: Testing for success with `assert` will not work if you compile in release mode (e.g. with `NDEBUG` defined). The correct way is with the if statement as shown in the example.

Comment: @Brandin - I am assuming that anyone who is hard wiring file paths to the current directory is working in debug mode, not release mode. But your point is (again) valid - thanks. Do you think it's worth removing the `assert` method from the answer?

Comment: I don't think removing the assert is a good move. "Are you sure the file opened correctly?" has been a useful comment in similar questions.