# exit-status-3221225477-in-terminal-in-golang

Tags: windows, go

when I am trying to run the following golang code , the output in the terminal is "exit status 3221225477". and then the program closed. I am using fyne GUI package. can you please help me with this issue.
    package main

```
import (
"net/url"
"fyne.io/fyne"
"fyne.io/fyne/app"
"fyne.io/fyne/layout"
"fyne.io/fyne/theme"
"fyne.io/fyne/widget"
)

func main() {
app := app.New()
app.Settings().SetTheme(theme.LightTheme())
entry := widget.NewEntry()
entry.SetText("Path")

w := app.NewWindow("Hello")

link, err := url.Parse("https://www.inovatian.com/")
if err != nil {
fyne.LogError("Could not parse URL", err)
}

w.SetContent(widget.NewVBox(
widget.NewLabelWithStyle("Welcome to Inovatian App", 
fyne.TextAlignCenter, fyne.TextStyle{Bold: true}),
layout.NewSpacer(),

widget.NewHyperlinkWithStyle("inovatian", link, fyne.TextAlignCenter, 
fyne.TextStyle{}),
layout.NewSpacer(),

widget.NewGroup("",
    fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewGridLayout(2),
        widget.NewButton("Next", func() {
            app.Quit()
        }),
        widget.NewButton("Cancel", func() {
            app.Quit()
        }),
      ),
    ),
))
w.CenterOnScreen()
w.Resize(fyne.NewSize(240, 180))
w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

Comment: Are there no other errors printed? any stack trace or failure information above the exit code?

Answer (score 3):

Works on ubuntu (screenshot below).

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106139/process-exited-with-return-value-3221225477), the return value 3221225477 in hex is 0xC0000005 or STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION, which go reports as "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference".
So it may be an issue in the windows version of the Fyne GUI library.

[This Fyne issue might be related](https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/issues/191).

[image: app screenshot]

Comment: thank's for your reply , but in my windows it doesn't work !!

Comment: Follow the fyne issue link and read through it: it looks as though this is a Windows OS and/or driver bug. You may be able to install a different Windows driver (or use a different video card) to work around it.

Comment: I can confirm it works on Windows 10 for me, so it's not the code at fault.
I think that Mark might be right and it's your windows graphics drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Your source code works fine on macOS Mojave as well.

[image: App]

Though, I am getting a warning that 'NSOpenGLContext' has been explicitly marked deprecated in macOS 10.14. (This should not come in Windows.)

[image: NSOpenGLContext is deprecated]

As Mark said, the return value 3221225477 in hex is 0xC0000005 ("Access violation"), it indicates that your program has terminated abnormally or crashed.

Comment: The deprecated warning goes away with the 1.3 release that is on "develop" branch at the moment :)